# How to classify tweets based on posters' demographic on Altmetric?

Tags: api, twitter

I requested `API from Altmetric` and can get the twitter information including `tweet id and tweeter id`.

`Altmetric` classify tweeter as Members of the public, `Scientists, Practitioners (doctors, other healthcare professionals), Science communicators (journalists, bloggers, editors), and Unknown`.

How can I classify the tweets into these categories?

Expecting to classify the tweets using the same categories as `Altmetric`.